# Architectural decision: Generic login application used from multiple projects?

Tags: java, maven, architecture, war, vaadin

I have requirement to unify login screen in multiple applications that we have (Java webapps). It is basically JSP page secured by Spring Security and on successful login it redirects to VAADIN servlet which creates some generic application view.

Other applications should be aple to add hooks (extend our generic vaadin view) and provide custom logic. I am familiar with maven and sharing JARs, but how am I supposed to share basically WAR? Is it possible to add some sort of dependency on application and inherit everything including WEB-INF itself with contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to share a jar file and make the specific applications to look for Spring Security configuractions inside the jar. Something like a classpath import:

```
<import resource="classpath:com/security/shared/securityContext.xml" />
```

And be sure that the login page is loaded from the jar using classpath resources or forward to a Single Sign-On server that has the page.

[Here](http://ocpsoft.org/java/jsf-java/how-to-modular-jsf-applications-with-cdi-and-prettyfaces/) is a good example of a modular app using Java EE technologies (not Spring) but I think the base idea will be helpful for your specific problem.

Comment: Is it possible to package WEB-INF to JAR?

Comment: WEB-INF is specific to a WAR file, if you have to put resources in your JAR file, they should be stored in the META-INF dir